# Call selenium click event using java

Tags: java, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYroB.jpg)

I am writing selenium test cases using java. I need to write click event. To trigger click event for the below button.

```
<button class="btn btn-block" id="employee_rightAll" type="button">
<i class="icon-forward"></i>
```

I used :   **By.id("employee_rightAll").click()**

How to trigger click event for the below button. Here there is no id attribute.

```
<button class="DualList_button_3xaWM" type="button">
  <i class="icon-forward"></i>
</button>
```

Let me write me query again

For button with id , I write click even as ***By.id("employee_rightAll").click()***

For button without id how to write the **click event** ?

Please patron me for basic question. Just started to work on selenium.

Due to security measures in company VM, it is not possible for me to copy stacktrace. Not able to add images due to lack of reputation point,otherwise I add stacktrace as image

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: I tried By.className("icon-forward")  
I got the below message
Unable to find element with class name == icon-forward

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: It is our company's internal portal

Comment: Please check if the button you are trying to click is inside a frame?

Comment: Inside one div we have five buttons. one of the button is I mentioned above. I am trying to click only forward button

Comment: Hi @SeleniumNewbie, Welcome to StackOverflow, Please add more details like Error trace, Console output, etc to your questions to get good answers. You can follow the below guidelines on how to ask a good question: - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this xpath instead :

```
//i[contains(@class, 'icon-forward')]/..
```

or `//button[contains(@class, 'DualList_button')]`

based on your code which is

```
By.id("employee_rightAll").click
```

you can click like this

```
 By.xpath("//i[contains(@class, 'icon-forward')]/..").click
```

But I think it should be `.click()` instead of `click`

More constructive way would be this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class, 'icon-forward')]/..")).click()
```

Comment: //button[contains(@class, 'DualList_button')] : I am getting error of "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The xpath expression '//button[contains(@class,'DualList_button'' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement

Comment: By.id("employee_rightAll").click()  for this one button has id attributes .

Comment: <button class="DualList_button_3xaWM" type="button">
  <i class="icon-forward"></i>
</button> this one don't have id attributes

Comment: <button class="btn btn-block" id="employee_rightAll" type="button">
<i class="icon-forward"></i>
I used : By.id("employee_rightAll").click : this one is working fine

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class, 'icon-forward')]/..")).click() - did u try this ? if yes what is the error

Comment: Yes I tried (By.xpath("//i[contains(@class, 'icon-forward')]/..")).click(). org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException " Unable to find element with id == criteria ( WARNNG: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Is it in iframe ? can you check ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. It is not in iframe

Comment: Can you share more HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[contains(@class,'DualList_button')]")).click();
```

Comment: we use waitForVisibilityAndFind function to handle selenium.getDriver().findElement(by)); For by variable we pass parameter : By.xpath(".//button[contains(@class,'DualList_button')]". Above comment failed and throw timeoutException in this  line

Comment: try without waitForVisibilityAndFind(). If the element is already present why are you waiting for the element to be visible which will fail and throw timeout exception.

Comment: waitForVisibilityAndFind() is standard that already followed in the code. So I follow them